# Venn Diagram in React JS

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, react-router, venn-diagram

I am using d3.js to create venn diagram in react js. While trying to create I use venn module. So I used below code for starting purpose

```
 var venn = require("venn");
 venn.create([1,2]);   
 console.log(venn);
```

While running the problem am getting following error

```
**Error: **define cannot be used indirect****


// Execute the module function
**modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));**
```

could anyone suggest me to resolve this issue.

Comment: can you please create a demo for it? would be easy to help. Also, in react, we don't do `require` rather we do `import venn or {venn} from 'venn';` The `require` way is for node app.

Comment: I followed following links to create a venn  -:diagramhttps://www.npmjs.com/package/venn

Comment: You can also just use png images, here's a collection of all 2set and 3set venn diagrams:  https://github.com/Ace-Cassidy/Venn-Diagram-Pictures

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";
import * as venn from "venn.js";
export const VennDiagram = (props) => {

  const [sets, setSets] = useState([
    { sets: ["I"], size: 1000, label: "IMPORTANT: Plan" },
    { sets: ["U"], size: 200, label: "URGENT: Delegate Next" },
    { sets: ["S"], size: 1000, label: "FIT: Make Time" },
    { sets: ["I", "U"], size: 300, label: "Delegate Now" },
    { sets: ["S", "U"], size: 300, label: "Do Next" },
    { sets: ["S", "I"], size: 300, label: "Schedule" },
    { sets: ["S", "I", "U"], size: 80, label: "Do Now" }
  ]);
  useEffect(() => {

    let chart = venn.VennDiagram();
    d3.select("#venn").datum(sets).call(chart);
  }, [sets]);

  return (
    <div id="venn" style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Could you please help me to reduce the width of this venn diagram ? also for circles width?

Comment: I think I had to use a fork of venn. 
https://github.com/upsetjs/venn.js

This lets you use viewBox. I think mine is something like:
`let chart = venn.VennDiagram().useViewBox().height(300)`

Comment: This works in React 18 as well Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment, you need to `import` it, instead of `requiring` it. `require` is a `CommonJS` syntax, usually found in `NodeJS` while `react` doesn't have that. It uses `import` syntax of ES6.

Here is what you can do:

1. Import it.

```js
import venn from "venn";
```

2. Use it inside your functional/class react component like this:

```js
let myVenn = venn.create([1, 2]);
console.log(m); // [1,2]
```

Also, here's a [simple demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-golick-1ocwc?fontsize=14) I have created for you. It works perfectly fine. Check the console section at the bottom right.