# Interactive 3 circle venn diagram in JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, venn-diagram, venn

Does anyone know of a library for interactive (hoverable) 3 circle venn diagrams in JS?
I need the areas to scale.

Things I tried:
https://www.highcharts.com/demo/venn-diagram/brand-light - Doesn't scale area

I am also going to try:
[Venn Diagram in React JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58129855/venn-diagram-in-react-js)

Answer (score 0):

There is a [venn.js](https://github.com/benfred/venn.js) library, based on d3.js by Ben Frederickson.
He describes the approach in his [blog post](http://www.benfrederickson.com/venn-diagrams-with-d3.js/).

Haven't used it myself, but looks interesting.

Here is a simple example (link to [github](https://github.com/benfred/venn.js/blob/master/examples/simple.html)):

```
// define sets and set set intersections
var sets = [ {sets: ['A'], size: 12},
             {sets: ['B'], size: 12},
             {sets: ['A','B'], size: 2}];

var chart = venn.VennDiagram();
d3.select("#venn").datum(sets).call(chart);
```

He also has example for interactive diagram: https://github.com/benfred/venn.js/blob/master/examples/interactive.html